# YahooFinancials module how to access historical balance sheet data

Tags: python, finance, yahoo

I am using the new Yahoofinancials Module to get financial statement data. Specifically the historical data from financial statements. The code I am using only returns the most recent piece of data. In the module description it states that

> Quarterly statement data returns the last 4 periods of data, while
>   annual returns the last 3.

How to access these last 3 or 4 periods of data?

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials as YF

tickers = ['aapl', 'fb', 'goog']
for ticker in tickers:
        yf = YF(ticker)
        CurrentAssets = yf._financial_statement_data('balance', 'balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly', 'totalCurrentAssets', 'quarterly')
```

This code will give me the most recent piece of data for the current assets. How can I access the older 3 or 4 data pieces?

Comment: Not having used the module, the first red flag I see is that you're directly accessing a (pseudo)private method, prefixed with an underscore. Is there a reason you're directly calling a helper method, rather than the built-in `get_financial_stmts()`, which is defined as "Public Method for the user to get financial statement data"?

Comment: I am doing it like that so that I can return only the current asset value, instead of returning the entire balance sheet.

Comment: I don't know if that is the best way, its just a way that i managed to get it to work

Comment: You can do that with https://investpy.readthedocs.io/_api/stocks.html?highlight=histor#investpy.stocks.get_stock_financial_summary . This will give you the last four quarterly balance sheets. I am searching for some API to give me even more (for the last five years). Let me know if you find something!